# Is visible on cached jQuery elements

Tags: jquery, performance

How do i check the visibility of cached jquery variables?

**Non cached**

```
  $('.elements:visible').length; // 45
```

**Cached** , better perfomance when accessing the variable multiple times

```
var elements = $('.elements');
// This is not working $(elements + ":visible").length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
elements.filter(':visible');
```